# Fix ugly col horizontal placement at extra small breakpoint bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have columns taking up proper width and stacking appropriately at all breakpoints. However, at the extra small breakpoint it is properly stacking content but harshly aligning the only content on the line all the way to the left. Is there a way to get the content from the stacked col to move over to the right at just the extra small breakpoint and not change anything else ?

I have tried `justify-content-*` but it does not apply to stacked content.

Comment: show us your code what you tried yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shift content on a stacked line by using `offset`. Since there is no class name for xs you have to set the general case and then override for every other breakpoint:

```
offset-2 offset-sm-0 offset-md-0 offset-lg-0 offset-xl-0 offset-xxl-0
```